# What do we mean by void 0 in this React Code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am aware what literal mean by void(0) || void 0

but i couldn't understand this snippet, i may not understanding void properly in context to `strict` mode

here is code in JSX

```
<button onClick={() => this.setState({ liked: true })}>
    Like
</button>
```

here is compiled code from babel which is equivalent to previous JSX snippet

```
"use strict";

var _this = void 0;

React.createElement("button", {
  onClick: function onClick() {
    return _this.setState({
      liked: true
    });
  }
}, "Like");
```

I feel like it is first set `_this` to undefined later at time of evaluation react-dom or reactjs does some kind of magic to convert it into this context.

Comment: it is declaring an initializing a global variable with `undefined`.

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks for answering,  Yes you are right, but how _this is evaluated here `return _this.setState({ liked: true });`

Comment: the variable is assigned with a new value/object somwhere in the code.

Comment: If that's literally the entire file that you've passed through Babel, then it is correct: `this` is undefined and will remain undefined. If that JSX were inside an actual React component then the compilation result would be different, `this` would refer to the component. The context matters, you can't compile disconnected snippets of code and expect the same results as when compiling them as part of an actual project.

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks for the information, is there any possibility i get detailed information, how and which react dependency is responsible for handling `_this` assignment process,

Comment: @GuyIncognito i understood your point, i was looking for bit inside from react core perspective, but thanks for your information

Comment: I don't think you really understood it if you're asking for the "_this assignment process" (there is no such thing.)

Comment: @GuyIncognito sorry if you didn't get my point, 
i said its same as you mentioned first _this set to undefined and then somewhere in code it is set to `this` context of that specific component
but any insight from core react perspective how they are handling these pieces 
thanks

Comment: I didn't say that, I said the opposite. "then somewhere in code it is set to this context of that specific component" <–- that is *not* what happens. *The `this` context never changes*.

Comment: @GuyIncognito you must have read this statement 
`I feel like it is first set _this to undefined later at time of evaluation react-dom or reactjs does some kind of magic to convert it into this context.`

i wanted to know how and which dependency managing this stuff

Comment: Nothing manages that stuff because it doesn't happen.

Comment: @GuyIncognito i re-read your first message, now it makes sense thanks brother for taking time and responding to my query